# Thrust OpenMP without CUDA?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, openmp, thrust

Can I use Thrust with the OpenMP device system if my machine doesn't have a CUDA GPU? If so, do I still require the CUDA toolkit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found this in the CUDA documentation:

*When using either the OpenMP or TBB systems, `nvcc` isn't required. In general, `nvcc` is only required when targeting Thrust at CUDA. For example, we could compile the previous code directly with `g++` with this command line:*

`$ g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -fopenmp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -lgomp -I<path-to-thrust-headers>`

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends

Comment: If I pass host_vector values to the thrust algorithms, they work at CPU, but if I pass device_vector values to the algorithms, they work at GPU. Is it the case that the algorithms that run at CPU use OpenMP and the ones that run at GPU use Cuda backend?